Can't include images etc. in drupal 7.101 some nodes but not in otherss
Drupal 7.101.
I have nodes in the site where any embedded objects do not appear but other in other content types (blogs) they do. In earlier releases of Drupal 7 there were no problems. Since then, the only significant change is that ckeditor 4 no longer works.
Any ideas why this is the case?
